# is signal handler code in a process paged?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

I have a question about linux signal handling mechanism. When a signal is to be delivered to a process, the kernel setups up the process stack(to do a successfull syscall back into the kernel using sys_sigreturn) and then does a sysexit/sysret to jump to the registered signal handler of the process. I am wondering what happens if the page in which the signal handler code is present, is paged out when the kernel does sysret ? The kernel does not expect page faults when executing ring 0 code right ?
Does the kernel keep process signal handling code pinned in memory always ?

Comment: The kernel has not a slightest shadow of an idea which pages contain signal handling code (it only knows a single entry address), and cannot possibly keep all these pages pinned to RAM. It doesn't need to, as signal handling code is not ring 0 code.

Comment: Right. i understand that. This is the situation im talking about. Sysret is a ring 0 instruction. Sysret tries to jump to a location in ring 3. If the page which contains signal handling code happens to be paged out, the Sysret instruction will cause a page fault because it is trying to access a page that has no mapping. What happens then ?

Comment: No, `sysret` will not cause a page fault. It does not access any memory, it only modifies the program counter and changes the privilege level. The page fault will occur when the CPU tries to read the next instruction, but the privilege level is already changed to ring 3 by then.

Comment: By the way as far as I understand you *can* have page faults in ring 0, if you are very careful.

Comment: @n.m.: as for the Linux kernel, IIRC a page fault in kernel mode should have an exception table associated, e.g: a copy_from_user() may page fault and jump to the exception handler associated, which would set the error return to -EFAULT. But all this is from memory, so don't trust me much.

Comment: Under what circumstances can you have page faults in the kernel? are you talking about functions like copy_from_user() etc like ninjalj pointed out ?

Comment: Wow. This is really interesting. I never bothered to look into code for copy_from_user() etc. I always assumed the kernel checked the PTE's directly to figure out if it was going to cause a page fault or not. I did not realize, copy_from_user() actually page faults and then jumps to the appropriate handler location based on rip/eip...Why do they not check the pte's directly anyway?

Comment: never mind. They dont check the pte's because the page might be paged out and they might need to page it in and can handle a host of other page fault related issues without repeating code.